# Get array for dropdown from foreach parent

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays (one inside the other), where one goes through a list of questions - and the other contains the list of options for the dropdown menu.

```
    <?php foreach ($modelSettings as $name=>$item):?>
            <select name="<?php echo 'model'.($i+1).'['.$name.']' ?>" >
                <?php foreach($item['options'] as $value):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $value?>"><?php echo ucfirst($value);?></option>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'model'.($i+1).'[id]'?>" value="0"/>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

The result looks like this

```
<select name="model4[car]">
<option value="bmw">BMW</option>
<option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<select name="model4[color]">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="white">White</option>
</select>
```

What I'm trying to do is to eliminate the first `foreach` so that I will write up every `<select>` manually, but have the list in the dropdown retrieved via an array.

I've been trying various things, among them this:

```
        <select name="model4[car]" >
            <?php foreach ($modelSettings as $name=>$item):?>
            <?php foreach($name[0] as $value):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value?>"><?php echo ucfirst($value);?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'model'.($i+1).'[id]'?>" value="0"/>
etc....
```

But I have been unsuccessful.

This is how the arrays are created in the backend.

```
public function getOptions()
    {
        $modelLabels = array('car' => __('Age'),
                            'color'=> __('Color'),
                            'fuel_type'=> __('Fuel Type'),
                            'transmission'=> __('Transmission'));

        $tmpModelSettings = $this->list_columns();
        unset($tmpModelSettings['id'], $tmpModelSettings['name']);
        $modelSettings = array();
        foreach($tmpModelSettings as $key=>$value)
        {
            $modelSettings[$key]['options'] = $value['options'];
            $modelSettings[$key]['label'] = $modelLabels[$key];
        }
        return $modelSettings;
    }
```

Sorry, I am new to this - and the PHP documentation did not help me to sufficiently understand code this complex (for me anyway :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt doesn't make much sense (why are you trying to iterate over a key reference?) You should access the particular array element within the `$modelSettings` array using the key reference. Then you can access the `options` element in that array subsequently and `foreach` over them.

```
<select name="model4[car]" >
    <?php foreach($modelSettings['car']['options'] as $value):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value?>"><?php echo ucfirst($value);?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'model'.($i+1).'[id]'?>" value="0"/>
```